# Can I play Sims 4 on my Mac using a PS3 controller?

Tags: controllers, macos, the-sims-4

Downloaded Sims 4 off Origin to play on my MacBook Air that is 6 months old. I'm finding it really difficult to play with a trackpad and thought "I will have to get a mouse!"

After Googling it I got a video of a guy using the Bluetooth on a Mac to connect a PS3 controller. Would this work for playing Sims 4? Could someone give me detailed instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting a Dualshock 3 controller to a MAc is possible via bluetooth: [**How to Connect a PlayStation 3 Controller to a Mac**](http://theultralinx.com/2014/02/connect-playstation-3-controller-mac-os-mavericks/)

But it looks like controller support for The Sims 4 will not be available: [**Sims 4(PC) To Enable Controller/Gamepad Support**](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-4/Sims-4-PC-To-Enable-Controller-Gamepad-Support/m-p/3439089#M5971) *(this question refers to PC specifically, but it's more than likely to apply cross platform)*

As RESPAWN has mentioned below, there are a couple of gamepad to keyboard/mouse mapper programs available for Macs: [**JoystickMapper**](http://joystickmapper.com/) and [**Enjoyable**](https://yukkurigames.com/enjoyable/)

Comment: A Google search turned up at least two pieces of software that seem to allow one to map a gamepad to keyboard and mouse controls.  I don't have a Mac anymore, so I can't test myself, but it sounds like either one would be the last piece of the puzzle.  Joystick Mapper: http://joystickmapper.com/.  Enjoyable: https://yukkurigames.com/enjoyable/.